# Dynamic Forms - disappearing divs on input selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

```
<form>
      <div class ="choose_level">
          <div class="row>
             <input id='level_1 tier1' name='signup_context[type_level]'                 type='radio' value='1'>
             <input id='level_2 tier1' name='signup_context[type_level]' type='radio' value='2'>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class='choose_style tile center hidden' data-behavior=''>
          <div class="row>
             <input id='level_3 ' name='signup_context[type_level2]'                 type='radio' value='3'>
             <input id='level_4' name='signup_context[type_level2]' type='radio' value='4'>
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

and the jquery

```
$('.choose_level.radio').click(function () {
     $(.choose_level).addClass('hidden');
     $(.choose_style).removeClass('hidden');
 });
```

When the user selects one of the two radio buttons in this first div, it should disappear and the next div containing the new options should appear.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.choose_level input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
     $('.choose_level').addClass('hidden');
     $('.choose_style').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: What if I want to have level_1 display a different div on select than level_2?

Comment: Then you have to check what value was selected, and act accordingly